# Getting An error occured (IncompleteSignature)when calling the list-users operation: 'iam' not a valid key-value pair(missing equal sign) in authoriz

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, identity-management

I assinged a role to an EC2 instance and when I am trying to preview the role in aws connect using 'aws iam list-users' I get an error message. I am not sure why I am getting this when a role is properly assigned to my ec2 instance.

I tried

1. detaching and re attaching a role
2. creating a new role and attaching that.
3. clearning aws connect content
4. tried rebooting my ec2 instance.

Comment: You can use `aws sts get-caller-identity` to see which role you are currently using. Check that to verify it is correct.